# Chromium does not accept CSP script-src SHA-256 hash

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I am using Chromium version 89.0.4389.90 for the following simple HTML snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test CSP</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
         content="script-src 'sha256-OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys='">
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">function test() { alert('Hello'); }</script>
   <button onclick="test();">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Creating the Base64-coded hash with:

```sh
$ echo -n 'function test() { alert('Hello'); }' | openssl sha256 -binary | openssl base64
OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys=
```

When loading this, the Chromium console prints...

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys='".
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-r+abGbElv1ENxT5+LrplDxvxZl4w3iy17u48CbdgB8g='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

If I click the button, another error message is printed:

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys='".
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

When I replace `OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys=` with `r+abGbElv1ENxT5+LrplDxvxZl4w3iy17u48CbdgB8g=` (as suggested in the error message), there isn't any error message on page load, but the error is still there when I click the button (and the script is not executed).

My questions:

1. What is going wrong?
2. What data is used from Chromium to calculate the suggested Base64 encoded SHA-256 hash, `r+abGbElv1ENxT5+LrplDxvxZl4w3iy17u48CbdgB8g=`?

Comment: The problem will be the `-binary` switch. You are hashing text, not binary data. Also there seems to be a quote in quote problem in `echo -n 'function test() { alert('Hello'); }'`

Comment: The `-binary` option is needed to ensure that the proper data are piped to the openssl base64 command. I had a problem with the quotes inside the text. When using `echo -n "function test() { alert('Hello'); }" | openssl sha256 -binary | openssl base64` the result is `r+abGbElv1ENxT5+LrplDxvxZl4w3iy17u48CbdgB8g=` as suggested from chromium. Question 2 is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain where the hash `OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys=` is coming from.

To verify what Chromium is outputting, generate the Base64 output manually using online tools (and verified again in C#):

```
SHA256: function test() { alert('Hello'); }
      = afe69b19b125bf510dc53e7e2eba650f1bf1665e30de2cb5eeee3c09b76007c8
Base64: afe69b19b125bf510dc53e7e2eba650f1bf1665e30de2cb5eeee3c09b76007c8
      = r+abGbElv1ENxT5+LrplDxvxZl4w3iy17u48CbdgB8g=
```

Which matches exactly what Chromium says it should be.  I would guess that there is an encoding/hashing problem with the method you are using.

**How Faulty Hash Was Produced**

You've obtained the Base64 output of `OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys=`.

This is from the SHA-256 hash produced from this text:

```
function test() { alert(Hello); }
```

**Notice the missing quotes around `Hello`**. @connexo's comment on the question provided the missing clue to figure out why the wrong hash was being produced.

The steps to reproduce the faulty hash (with missing quotes around `Hello`):

```
SHA256: function test() { alert(Hello); }
      = 3ad7a249f8caf9cd685cba2d0b8263e1b267f29768e8de275a4f2e4554cceb2b
Base64: 3ad7a249f8caf9cd685cba2d0b8263e1b267f29768e8de275a4f2e4554cceb2b
      = OteiSfjK+c1oXLotC4Jj4bJn8pdo6N4nWk8uRVTM6ys=
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your method of hashing, in detail.

Comment: @connexo Any online site using SHA256 hashing produces the hash I indicated.  Also tested in C# which produces the same hash.  What is your comment alluding to?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure your answer is reproducible for OP, and also for future visitors. As the method of creating the hash appears to be the source of the problem, it matters.

Comment: @connexo In other news, your comment to OP's question has allowed reproduction of the faulty hash due to missing quotes.  I've updated the answer to show this

Comment: Ok, the mismatching base64 hash is caused by wrong quotes in command (see also comment on question). But when using the correct hash, chromium does not accept the button click ... why?

Comment: Remaining problem is caused by onclick() handler method, which is not covered by the CSP hash. The link [https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-hashes/](https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-hashes/) helps to understand the problem and shows how to solve this problem without using `unsafe-hashes`.